# What is the difference between ERC20.transferFrom and IERC20.transferFrom?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, interfaces

Calling ether of these in my contract does the same thing. What is the difference then?

```
ERC20(tokenAddress).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);

IERC20(tokenAddress).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
```

I thought IERC20 was just the interface so I would have to implement the function myself. But both transfer the token between addresses.

Could I have a caching problem, or do they actually do the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're effective the same thing in this case.

But what ERC20 does that's different from IERC20 is that it's importing the **entire** contract API, as opposed to the public bits.

When you're using IERC20, there's zero chance you'll accidentally tie into custom functionality.  That's why it's better.  you're aiming for a smaller interface, so it keeps the design cleaner.